# how can I make more than 1 max?

Tags: ddms

I want to know how can I make 2 max

Comment: Use a group by clause

Comment: Your database isn't normalized. Don't do separate columns like "product1", "product2", "product3". Instead, each product have its own ID.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White how?

Comment: You've not provided a tag for the specific DBMS you're using or the expected output you want to obtain. Without that information, your question is difficult to answer - if someone takes the time to write an answer and then finds out it won't work on your DBMS or it doesn't do what you really wanted, it wastes both their time and yours. Hover your mouse over the SQL tag you used and read the text in the pop-up window that appears, and then [edit] your post.

Comment: @gorpe This is very basic stuff. Please Google a bit before adding bloat to StackOverflow.

Comment: why did you remove the table

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't say which database you are using, I will assume it's PostgreSQL.

You may be looking for `GREATEST()`. For example:

```
select greatest(product1, product2, product3) from t;
```

Result:

```
greatest
--------
9
8
10
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/diPDYF4o).

Answer (score 0):

First let me thank you for a different question, it actually had me thinking.

Assuming tsql:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (id INT, num1 INT, num2 INT, num3 INT)

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES (1, 25, 36, 56), (2, 75, 43, 64)

SELECT max(pivotvals.val)
FROM @data d
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (d.num1), (d.num2), (d.num3)
) AS pivotvals (val)
```

result: 75